# how to compare two lists output from firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching a list using streambuilder from firebase and then compare with another list(Streambuilder) from firebase in flutter. how to compare?
eg: 1 person has 1000 followers and when 2nd person vists 1st person followers it has to show whether the followers(1st person) are also in his(2nd person) list or not.

below image is where i am fetching followers data of another person from firebase. also i have to check whether the followers of another person is in my following list or not.

```
    class FollowersWid extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userid;
  FollowersWid(this.userid);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users/$userid/followers')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, fetchedData) {
        if (fetchedData.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          return Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
              elevation: 8,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: fetchedData.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    UnFollow(fetchedData.data.docs[index]['username'], userid)
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet what you have achieved so far?

Comment: Hi , please see the uploaded image.i am fetching followers data of unknown person from firebase. also i have to check whether the followers of unknown person is in my following list or not.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use `.where` and `.contains` eg.

```dart
List firebaseList1 = [0, 5, 1];
List firebaseList2 = [1, 0, 2];
print(firebaseList1.where((item) => firebaseList2.contains(item)));
//output: (0,1)
```